# AC power on my laptop freezes

Tags: troubleshooting, power, toshiba-laptop

AC power on my laptop Toshiba satellite freezes and I have to forcibly off it by computer power button. and to start it on battery power now, Windows Vista will recommended start with repair option.

My computer works fine on battery power, so every time I have to shut off my computer and charge the battery in idle condition then use it for 2hrs on battery power, and again put off computer for recharging.  Can any one tell me why it hangs on AC power ON, I have tried AC power adapter but problem remains.  my computer using shared graphic card on motherboard.

Answer (score 1):

It is due fault in power section of laptop motherboard, need to replaced or repaired. Usually Toshiba M200, M100 have this problem . Faulty power mangement chip gets heated up while charging from ac mains , runs fine on battery.

Answer (score 1):

I use a HP ProBook, and when I turn on the AC power, the laptop freezes about 8 to 10 minutes, and then runs fine after that if I stop further alteration during freezing time.

I think there is a problem in the power section. A temporary way to get rid of this: When your laptop battery is running out of power and you going to connect AC supply:

- first set your system on "Power save" mode,
- put the system on sleep, then turn on AC supply,
- now turn your system ON, now it will work fine with AC plug.

You can shutdown your laptop before turning on AC, but it consumes more time so rather put it to sleep before connecting the AC power.